# Access images in Windows Phone Class Library

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, class-library

I want to access some images in my Windows Phone class library, but how can I access these images?

I have a method which will set the image, but

```
new Uri("/Assets/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

doesn't work. I've tried setting the image to Resource instead of Content, but it also doesn't work.

So how can I provice images in my class library?

Comment: do you use Portable Class Library? Or Windows Phone Class Library? These are a different types.

Comment: I'm using Windows Phone Class Library.

Comment: So why did you put PCL tag?

Comment: Because Im not using Portable Class Library, so I don't put PCL tag.

Comment: I removed the Portable Class Library tag :) Anyway, add more details to your question: where and how do you store the image? Show us the full method which you use to get the image and how are you trying to show in in the UI.

Comment: @atticus3000 did you find any soultion for this , if so please post it  here, it will help me

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather it looks like you are trying to set the source of an image from the XAML code behind file.

If so you can do so as follows:

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Hope this helps.